# How to get rid of the endless loop?

Tags: c#

i am new in the c# world. i've been working on a Program to determine Grades of students from the scores input which is a range of 1 and 100. but it keeps looping from beginning to end almost infinitely. here is the program pls what can i do....?

```
namespace ExamScore
{
    class YourExamScore
    {
        public string ExamScore(int[] value, int startindex, int endindex)
        {
            bool YourExamScore;
            var terminate = -1;


            for (var index = 0; index <= 100; index++)
            {

                if (YourExamScore = (value[90] <= value[99]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have An Excellent Score");
                }
                else if (YourExamScore = (value[70] <= value[89]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have a Good Score");
                }
                else if (YourExamScore = (value[50] <= value[69]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have a Satisfactory Score");
                }
                else if (YourExamScore = (value[0] <= value[49]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have a Satisfactory Score");
                }
                else
                {
                    return terminate.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "";

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int YourExamScore;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input Your Exam Score");
                YourExamScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            { 
            var e = new YourExamScore();
            var value = new int[100] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
           31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,
           64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100};

                    Console.WriteLine(e.ExamScore(value, 90, 100));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ExamScore(value, 70, 89));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ExamScore(value, 50, 69));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ExamScore(value, 0, 49));
                    Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and Output this

> You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score
>   You Have An Excellent Score

Comment: I can't see anything in that code that would make it *loop endlessly*?

Comment: You have a logical issue in checking the conditions to decide result

Comment: *"keeps looping from beginning to end **almost infinitely**"*. No, it runs the loop 101 times, as written in the `for` condition (`index <= 100`). First decide what the `value` parameter holds. "Value" is a poor naming choice for a parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `index` variable at least *somewhere* ?

Comment: @Groo: 101 times, due to using `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: this program appears to be doing exactly what it should, unless you can clarify your question?

Comment: @Jon: thanks, I updated the comment in the meanwhile.

Comment: The more I look at your code the less I understand what you are trying to achieve. What are you hoping for?

Comment: This is one of those questions where it's difficult to say where to start. Besides such minor errors as `=` instead of `==`, and the fact that the `<=` stuff was probably intended for range comparison, what's the use of having `values` where `values[i]==i+1`? Why have the loop at all? What is `terminate` for? Why the multiple calls to `ExamScore` with the same score? OP seems to be in the dark about what he's doing.

Comment: wow... guys calm down. I already said i was new in the Language, i'll try the suggested replies and get back. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loop, or the array at all:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input Your Exam Score");
        var examScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var grade = GetGrade(examScore);
        Console.WriteLine(grade);
    }

    private static string GetGrade(int examScore)
    {
        if (examScore >= 90)
            return "Excellent";

        if (examScore >= 70)
            return "Good";

        return "Satisfactory";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer (at the time of posting) that actually does what the OP is trying to achieve. The only issue I have is that you didn't include conditions for scores below 0 and above 100, which seems to be what the OP was trying to do with his/her `terminate` variable.

Comment: @JW: I actually first thought about adding a range check at the beginning of the method, and throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but then I removed it because it seemed it would unnecessarily confuse OP. Yes, returning the string `"-1"` would (I guess) be closer to OP's intents (but I doubt that that is an actual requirement of this homework, or whatever it is). You might also notice that I didn't return exact phrases as OP either, to keep code shorter. There might have been some laziness involved also. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are not comparing `==` they are assigning `=` which will always be true for the first if evaluated

Comment: Nope, they are assigning a boolean to be compared on... that is weird, but correct.

Comment: Ohh This is confusing, because the YourScore in the Main is defined as int, I didn't see ther was a bool Yourscore on the ExamScore context

Answer (score 0):

For the conditions you should write:

```
int score = value[index];
if (90 <= score && score <= 99))
{
     Console.WriteLine("You Have An Excellent Score");
}
// ... etc.
```

Hope this is what you meant by infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your program in a more efficent way:

```
public class ScoreRange {
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And your main:

```
int YourExamScore;
Console.WriteLine("Input Your Exam Score");
YourExamScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        List<ScoreRange> ranges = new List<ScoreRange>();
        ranges.Add(new ScoreRange() {
            Min = 0,
            Max = 49,
            Message = "You Have a Satisfactory Score"
        });
        ranges.Add(new ScoreRange() {
            Min = 50,
            Max = 69,
            Message = "You Have a Satisfactory Score"
        });
        ranges.Add(new ScoreRange() {
            Min = 70,
            Max = 89,
            Message = "You Have a Good Score"
        });
        ranges.Add(new ScoreRange() {
            Min = 90,
            Max = 100,
            Message = "You Have An Excellent Score"
        });



        string message = ranges.First(x => x.Min <= YourExamScore && YourExamScore <= x.Max).Message;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Be aware that you should to check YourExamScore range to be between 0 and 100